# STM32L0 series current consumption oscillation

Tags: current, stm32, low-power, power-consumption

I'm working on a low power project that my micro-controller can only have 1 mA in 2.7 V.
My micro-controller is STM32L051C8 and its works nice with its peripherals (ADC and Timer) and its current consumption is about 0.65 mA.
But After working for A few minutes the current consumption Suddenly jumps to higher numbers(about 2 to 8 mA !!) and coming back to 0.65 mA after seconds and again it works nice for A few minutes and  this chain continues irregularly .

I'm working with STM32L031 before and have the same problem. you guys think what is the reason ?

Comment: Either you're doing something that causes higher power consumption, or you're actually browning out from the meter burden voltage and getting an artificially low number because the MCU is not running.  Your goals *should* be achievable when running off the MSO without PLL multiplication and care not to drive signals against pulling resistors, etc, but no one is going to be able to tell you exactly what is wrong until you make more investigation of the system.

Comment: Get a serial port going to give commentary on what your program is doing and insert human scale time delays so that you have time to look at the current as it passes through various operational phases.  Disable functionality you think might be causing high current and see what sort of change results.  Consider other things on the board beyond the MCU, bus contentions, etc...

Comment: Thank you Chris for your tips.
But when current consumption is about 0.65 mA the micro controller is connected to the debugger and I can see the ADC working well and either with oscilloscope I can see the PWM signal, so it think that time it works well.

Comment: My code is simple and an operation is repeated regularly. so when irregularly current consumption is change there is not any new to make this happen

Comment: Could the debugger be causing it?

Comment: Without details and conclusions from meaningful investigations of the sort mentioned no one who doesn't have the hardware in front of them is going to be able to help you.  Low power design is not simple.

Comment: Aaron I don't think because this when i disconnect the debugger this problem still occurs.

Comment: Yes chris your right its not simple.
Let me try to tell you more I hope it can help.
I have only one stm32l051c8 connect to power and one analogue signal comes to this micro ADC(PA0) from another device(it consumption is not important with common GND). the other signal from this stm32l051c8 is one PWM signal from PA1 to an opamp(it's input impedance is infinite so دo current flows from this side) I have connected the VDD,VDDA,VSS,.. with 100nF caps and one 32.768khz oscillator to PC14 and PC15. 
This is all of my hardware Which can consume a maximum current of one milliampere.

Comment: I think it can because of problem in system clock configuration in programming side.
Or can maybe my micro-controller was not from original distributor and is from Chinese miscellaneous ones?

Comment: I have often found when aiming for low current that floating digital inputs can cause a problem.  They float around and behave for a while but when near the transition point they are prone to oscillate and can cause current draw.  Try attaching pull-up or pull-down resistors to unused inputs and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you john I will try this soon and tell you that works or not. I only use 2 pin of the micro-controller and all of the pins are float now.

Comment: John thank you so much for your useful tips.
All the night I have worked on your suggestion and connect all floating pins with a 16K resistor to Ground. and now my micro-controller works very well and now هt works for about an hour without current fluctuations.
Thank you again and again dear John.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead the actual issue with what you reference is not *oscillation* but rather shoot-through from having both input FET's partially on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on John's answer to my question, the answer is to add a Pull-Down resistor to all micro-controller floating pins. In this case, current consumption jumping is no longer observed in micro-controller.
Thank you John Birckhead.

Comment: You can do that with the internal pulling resistors, or simply by setting unused pins to analog mode

Comment: First I check the internal pull-down or analog mode but after afew minutes I see the jump in current consumption.
But when I connect them with resistor to GND it works with out problem.
you think what is the reason?

Comment: It would appear your program is allowing the chip configuration to change, perhaps by misoperating due to a programming error.  But as before, without details this is really unanswerable.  All you have are *guesses*.